# PHP - How to strip all characters that I want to be stripped using trim optional character_mask

Tags: php

I need some help understanding the trim function.
From the docs, its says the following about character_mask:

> character_mask
>   Optionally, the stripped characters can also be specified using the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

When I test by specifying `trim($num,"$\,")`, its not working as I expected.

```
$num = '$1,000.00';

$findSymbol = strpos($num, '$'); // find $ symbol
if ($findSymbol === false) {
    $num = $num;
}else{
    $num = trim($num,"$\,"); // strip the $ and the , symbol
}

var_dump($num); //OUTPUT: 1,000.00
```

Basically, all I want is strip the `$` and the `,` symbols all together so the output would look like this:

```
1000.00
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: >When I test by specifying trim($num,"$\,"), its not working as I expected. - I guess the reason is that you haven't escaped the backslash. Just edit the mask as `$\\,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) strips the listed characters from the beginning and/or end of the string as described in the docs you've quoted.

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

If you want to remove characters from the middle of a string, use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$num = str_replace(['$', ','], '', $num);
```

You can also use the two functions in combination:

```
$num = str_replace(',', '', trim($num, '$'));
```

Comment: thanks but since there is an optional `character_mask` so I was hoping I can achieve that using the options.

Comment: Well I'm afraid you can't use the list of characters to specify where in the string that character must be removed..... trim() is very specific about position, either beginning and/or end, but not in the middle

Comment: i see. thanks. btw your code results in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Yes, I'd missed a comma, fixed now

Comment: thanks, which one is lighter? str_replace or preg_replace as suggested by others?

Comment: There's barely any measurable time difference between the two, so you're best basing your decision on readability than on speed.... Using str_replace() is easier for other developers to understand what it's doing, but preg_replace() has the advantage of working with any currency symbols like £ or  € or ¥

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by removing every character expect allowed(in this case these are `0-9` and `.`)

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $num );
```

it will remove all character other than `0-9` and `.`

```
$num = '$1,000.00';
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $num );
```

[OutPut](http://codepad.org/0fPCtqgA)

```
1000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_replace`

```
$num = '$1,000.00';

$findSymbol = strpos($num, '$'); // find $ symbol
if ($findSymbol === false) {
    $num = $num;
}else{
    //$num = trim($num,"$\,"); // strip the $ and the , symbol
    $num = str_replace(array('$',','), "", $num);

}

var_dump($num); //OUTPUT: 1,000.00
```

Comment: @anagnam how its working when you are telling `all I want is strip the $ and the , symbols `?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all in one line with str_replace + array.

```
echo str_replace(['$', ','], null, '$1,000.00');
```

1000.00